# Conditional button in CollectionView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app, I have a `CollectionView` that displays a list of products. The product class has a `Type` property that can have 3 possible values:

- New Arrival
- On Sale
- Clearance Item

I need to show a button if the type is "Clearance Item" that will open up a modal when the user clicks it and allow the user to make an offer.

How do I conditionally display this button?

```
<CollectionView
   x:Name="ProductsList"
   ItemsSource={Binding Products}>
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Frame
            BackgroundColor="#e7e7e7">
            <Frame.Content>
               <Label
                  Text={Binding ProductName}/>
               <Button
                  Text="Make Offer"
                  Command={Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ProductsList}, Path=BindingContext MakeOfferCommand}
                  CommandParameter={Binding .}
            </Frame.Content>
         </Frame>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

In the example above, the button shows all the time. I need to hide it when the product `Type` is "New Arrival" or "On Sale".

Comment: bind IsVisible to the Type property and use an IValueConverter to convert it to a bool

Comment: Here is a link for how to use converters that @Jason mentioned  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Looks like there are some built-in converters in Xamarin Community Toolkit. I'll play with them too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[Data-triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers) can do.

```
    <Button
        IsVisible="false"
        Text="Make Offer"
        Command={Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ProductsList}, Path=BindingContext MakeOfferCommand}
        CommandParameter={Binding .}>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ProductsList}, Path=BindingContext.Type}"
                TargetType="Button"
                Value="Clearance">
                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```